# How to remove duplicate nodes based on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

Please help me in removing the duplicate nodes from the xml.Condition to remove duplicate nodes is  quite complicated.

Condition 1:In each policy node under policyKey node i have to check policyNbr and PolicyFormCode/code and policyEffectiveDt and policyID
are same in all the policy nodes if they are same i have retain only the policy node which has sourceSystemCd/code='SCBP' present in it.

Condition 2 :If in the above condition policyNbr and PolicyFormCode/code and policyEffectiveDt and policyID any of this have differnt values i need to display all th policy node.

Condtion 3 :In the policy 1 and policy 2 policyNbr and policyFormCd should be same , then we have to disaply policy with policyId in it.If not equal then display both. Is this possible ? All the conditions should work in single xsl.

Condition 1:
Input xml:

```
    <policies>
    <!-- policy 1-->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>4567</policyNbr>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>669</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>ARA</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy> 
    <!-- policy 2-->
      <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>4567</policyNbr>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyID>54545</policyID>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>669</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy> 
    <!-- third -->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>1234</policyNbr>
            <policyID>115774001</policyID>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>660</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>ARAR</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy>
    <!-- fourth  -->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>660</code>
            </policyFormCd>
            <policyID>115774001</policyID>
            <policyNbr>1234</policyNbr>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy>
</policies>
```

Expected Output for conndition 3:

```
<policies>
 <!-- policy 2-->
    <policy>
    <policyKey>
        <policyNbr>4567</policyNbr>
        <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
        <policyID>54545</policyID>
        <policyFormCd>
            <code>669</code>
        </policyFormCd>
    </policyKey>
    <transactionSplitTrans>
        <sourceSystemCd>
            <code>SCBP</code>
        </sourceSystemCd>
    </transactionSplitTrans>
</policy>
</policies>
```

Condition 1 and Condition 2 working fine for belwo xslt. need to include condition 3 in same xsl.

Comment: In your example above, the second and policies have different "policyEffectiveDt" values. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim,i have corrected it. it is same policyEffectiveDate now.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks a lot. Its working fine , but i have one more conditions to be satisfied.Can you please help me in it.condition 3

Comment: Hi Tim, I made Condition 3 working. by aading this code<xsl:key name="policy2" match="policy" use="concat(translate(policyKey/policyNbr,'0*',''), '|',policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|',policyKey/policyFormCd/code)"/>   <xsl:template match="policy[count(key('policy2', concat(translate(policyKey/policyNbr,'0*',''), '|', policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|', policyKey/policyFormCd/code))) > 1 and transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd/code != 'SCBP']"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a key to "group" the duplicates. It will be a concatenated key to include all the fields

```
<xsl:key 
    name="policy"
    match="policy" 
    use="concat(policyKey/policyNbr, '|',
                policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|',
                policyKey/policyFormCd/code, '|',
                policyKey/policyID)" />
```

Then, you can have a template to ignore templates like so:

```
    <xsl:template match="policy[count(
      key('policy', concat(policyKey/policyNbr, '|', 
                           policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|', 
                           policyKey/policyFormCd/code, '|', 
                           policyKey/policyID))) > 1 
      and transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd/code != 'SCBP']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key 
        name="policy"
        match="policy" 
        use="concat(policyKey/policyNbr, '|',
                    policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|',
                    policyKey/policyFormCd/code, '|',
                    policyKey/policyID)" />

    <xsl:template match="policy[count(key('policy', concat(policyKey/policyNbr, '|', policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|', policyKey/policyFormCd/code, '|', policyKey/policyID))) > 1 and transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd/code != 'SCBP']" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, i added xsl:key for condition 3 its working.<xsl:key name="policy2" match="policy" use="concat(translate(policyKey/policyNbr,'0*',''), '|',policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|',policyKey/policyFormCd/code)"/><xsl:template match="policy[count(key('policy2', concat(translate(policyKey/policyNbr,'0*',''), '|', policyKey/policyEffectiveDt, '|', policyKey/policyFormCd/code))) > 1 and transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd/code != 'SCBP']"/>